# Lazy Loading HTML5 Section with Images

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, lazy-loading

I have a portfolio section on my single page site (site is divided into sections by HTML5 section Tag).

```
 <section id="portfolio" class="light-bg">
```

The portfolio section contains all images ( 16 MB).

```
<!-- Portfolio item -->
    <div class="item graphic-design">
      <a href="#folio-popup">
        <img src="img/portfolio/graphic-design/felicity/2.jpg" alt="Portfolio"/>
        <div class="details">
        <h4 class="title">Felicity</h4>
             <p class="des decription">
              6 day count down teaser for Felicity'14.
             </p>
        </div>
         <i class="icon-share-alt"></i>
           <div class="overlay"></div>
         </a>
    </div>
<!-- /Portfolio item -->
```

The site has a preloader which loads the site only after all content is downloaded causing a lot of waiting time.

Is there a lazy loading technique that can be applied on HTML5 sections which would cause the Portfolio section images to load only when the 'Portfolio' section is clicked? This would save on the preloading time.

The site is [here](http://shubhamrathi.in) and its files are [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B0byAC8kZZPhQ3h5SS1RMElodVE&usp=sharing). The index.html ( which has all sections is [here](http://pastebin.com/gGipwvQm).

Any other advice on how load time could be optimized?

Comment: Your picture responsiveness don't change onresize if after it was loaded in smaller screen.

Comment: Your page takes 33 seconds to load and includes 13mb of images, 500kb of JS, 500kb or CSS, etc. You can test it [here](http://www.webpagetest.org/). You will need to do more than just lazyload images to achieve reasonable performance.

Comment: @Roberto: I'm planning to add server caching. That should help too.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but that doesnt seem to improve the performance. Have I done anything wrong? The site is here: https://goo.gl/0kvDFX

Answer (score 2):

You can change the `<img>`s to something like:

```
<img data-src="img/portfolio/graphic-design/felicity/2.jpg" alt="Portfolio"/>
```

and change the `data-src` attribute to `src` with JavaScript when needed, for example when Portfolio section is clicked.

Example JavaScript code:

```
someElement.addEventListener("click", function() {
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("img[data-src]"))
    .forEach(element=> {
      element.src = element.getAttribute("data-src")
      element.removeAttribute("data-src")
    })
})
```

jQuery version:

```
$jQueryElement.click(function() {
  $("img[data-src]").attr("src", function() {
    return $(this).attr("data-src")
  }).removeAttr("data-src")
})
```

Comment: Up voted as this is a nicely coded answer. Yet, I think OP's web site has multiple problems to solve that aren't part of the question.

Comment: $('#portfolio').addEventListener()
->VM794:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).addEventListener is not a function(…)

Comment: @Shubham Ahem... `someElement` should be native DOM element, not a jQuery element. If you're using jQuery, it should be just `$someElement.click(function() { ... })`.